# API request does not authenticate

Tags: rest, http, get, postman, http-get

Using [this documentation](https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#introduction) I'm trying to test the request using Postman the example on the right side:

```
$ curl https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/organizations
  -H 'Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.41d9f2cfbd1b7a8f9e314b7aff7bc2d1.8fcc9810810a216793f385b9dd6e125f'
  -H 'X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid: 10234695'
```

Maybe I'm not setting the parameters right but this is how it looks for the moment.

A new GET Request, in the url input: `https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/organizations`
And under that, in the Headers tab I added two key-value pairs:

`Authorization:`     `Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.41d9f2cfbd1b7a8f9e314b7aff7bc2d1.8fcc9810810a216793f385b9dd6e125f`
`Authorization:`     `X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid: 1023469`

The returned result:

```
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

If I deleted the second key-value pair it returns this JSON:

```
{
    "code": 57,
    "message": "You are not authorized to perform this operation"
}
```

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: I think that you should look at the *server-side* log files next.  What does the server log when it says, "bad request?"

Comment: Also:  it's quite possible that the two responses are unrelated.  The "not authorized" response probably means that your authorization-token is being *accepted.*  The "bad request" response (although curious that it's not JSON) implies ... well ... that the server really does think that your *(properly authorized, now ...)* request somehow **is** "bad!"

Comment: You are using default parameters! 
Change with your authorization token and your organization ID

Comment: @MikeRobinson do you mean to check DevTools' console? it is empty

Comment: It is just an example of how to use the API. The token expires after a short while and needs to be re-generated. Read https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/#oauth on how to create your own tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

If you are sure of the api url, do validate the token and create a fresh token and 
add it to header as below:

HeaderName : *Authorization*

HeaderValue: *1000.41d9f2cfbd1b7a8f9e314b7aff7bc2d1.8fcc9810810a216793f385b9dd6e125f*

HeaderName : *X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid*

HeaderValue: *10234695*

I tried this and is getting,

```
{
"code": 14,
"message": "Invalid value passed for authtoken."
}
```

Might be the token got invalid.

Now I tried with a new token generated myself and I am getting now,

```
{
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"organizations": [],
}
```

[image: Scrrenshot tried through AdvancedRESTClient, just another Postman]

**In short, you have to generate an auth token first and then hit the url with proper header value as shown above.**

Thank you :)